# German city names look weird in Careers ads

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

German place names in Careers entries are extended with their formal administrative prefixes:

- Stadtkreis Karlsruhe (should be: Karlsruhe)
- Stadtteil Darmstadt (should be: Darmstadt, also "Stadtteil" ("Borough") is nonsense? It's a city.)
- Gemeinde Goppingen (should be: Göppingen; the Umlaut is a separate issue)

This kind of notation may be the formally correct name for the place (when it's not flat-out wrong as it is for Darmstadt), but like elsewhere in the world, normal people never use it. This is like saying "City and County of San Francisco" instead of just "San Francisco".

This looks weird to the point of confusing users as to where the job actually is located; where a city is also a county ("Stadtkreis"), it also suggests that the job is only in the city's *vicinity*.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the external service we're using to geo-code locations had a little bit of a hiccup and decided to add those prefixes for a short period of time.

Only a small number of job listings were affected which we've fixed manually. Enjoy Careers ads free of all Stadtkreise, Ortsbezirke and Gemeindeverwaltungsverbände!

Comment: It still occasionally pops up, like here: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/35475/software-entwickler-w-m-wisag-facility-service?a=FUDYdTG possibly a relic though

Comment: More: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/36537/kernel-developer-m-w-astaro-co-kg-a?a=HardYEo http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/36540/software-developer-linux-network-m-w-astaro-co-kg-a?a=HaEQITu http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/36510/java-entwickler-m-w-semedy?a=H8sBgsw

Comment: Turned out the geo-coding service has some language-specific behavior we needed to account for. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Looking good, thanks!